# Is defining a variable using a for loop possible in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I'd want to do `for i in range(10): x+= 1` it obviously wouldn't work since `x` is undefined, I'd have to declare `x` e.g. `x=0` before trying to write to it, but now I have two lines, one for declaring `x=0` and one for actually writing the data I want to `x` (`for i in range(10): x+= 1`).

I was wondering, is there a way to do this in a single line? Or more specifically, declaring `x` as the result of a for loop?

Something along the lines of  `x = for i in range(10): x+= 1` ?

Would this even be possible or am I asking a nonsense question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with a `for` statement.

However, you can use a similar construct, such as a list comprehension expression or a generator expression:

```
x = sum(i for i in range(10))
```

which is equivalent to just saying

```
x = sum(range(10))
```

Edit: as Dougal correctly notes, in your example you increment by 1, so the equivalent is

```
x = sum(1 for i in range(10))
```

which is in turn the same as `x = len(range(10))` or just `x = 10`.

Comment: Note that this isn't the same thing as OP's code; that was `sum(1 for i in range(10))`, or equivalently `len(range(10))`, which of course is just `10`.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, i would imagine you would just want to use `x` as the loop variable:

```
for x in range(10): pass#or range(1,11)
```

An `enumerate` would also achieve a similar effect as what you are describing, assuming you want a different variable as the loop variable so as to do something else in the loop:

e.g.

```
for i,x in enumerate(range(x_start,x_end+1)): 
    #do something
```